# Why are digits used as indentification instead of letters?

Tags: database, structure

Why are numbers used as ID in databases (think primary key + AI) and pretty much everywhere instead of letters?
There are 10 digits available, while the English alphabet has as much as 26 letters.

Let's say that each letter/digits takes a spot. *98* takes two spots and *1202* takes four, etc. In four spots, you can store up to 10 000 IDs, but if you use letters instead, you could store as much as 456 976 IDs with the same amount of spots. Even more if you'd use case-sensitivity. **That's almost 50 times more.**

I do realize that this most likely doesn't matter for the regular user, but why aren't larger databases using letters instead of digits as IDs?

Comment: An edit to make the question more understandable (including tags) would be appreciated. English isn't my native language hence I find it quite hard to make myself understood sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing characters for numeric values.

An ID column that uses an integer (say a 32bit Integer) as the data type will only take 4 bytes *per* row. It will also be a native value in memory and can be acted on natively in the CPU (as a binary representation).

This is not the same for characters - even if one assumes ASCII (8bit) is used, the moment you go over 4 characters, you are using more space. You also need to translate between the values in order to make valid comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers pack better.  You suppose that because the numbers are displayed in decimal, that they are stored as decimal, but they're really binary.  Optimized for computers :).

If you want to represent one of 26 letters, you need 2<sup>5</sup> binary digits.  You lose 32-26=8 possible digits per block of 5 bits.

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard and fast rule that says you can't use alphanumeric fileds as IDs in databases.  People do it all the time.

As for why it's more common to use numbers...

- Most database systems are designed with auto-increment ability on numbers. (Yeah I know, that's a chicken/egg scenario)
- Numbers can/usually do take up less bytes of storage. (Yes, you can store large numbers and shorter strings to overcome this, but as a general rule...)

  - I was going to expand on this, but everyone else beat me to the punch with accurate descriptions of the difference between bytes needed to store an int compared to a varchar.  It would be silly to add it now.  ;-)
- On every system I've worked with, sorting on numbers is different than sorting on strings:

  - The values 1, 12,3, 2, 20 are sorted numerically as 1,2,3,12,20, but when sorted alphanumerically: 1,12,2,20,3
- More computational power is needed to overcome the previous point, so numbers are simply more efficient to work with.

  - This is the answer to why most databases are designed with auto-incrementing numbers as opposed to auto-incrementing strings in the first bullet.  Whether it's the chicken or the egg, I'll leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Because computers only work with numbers. Even characters are treated by the computer as numbers.

Also, using character strings is much LESS efficient than numbers.

Any number smaller than 4,294,967,296 (2^32) can be stored in only 4 bytes, whereas even a *5* character (and each character takes up one byte) alphabetic string allows only 11,881,376 possibilities.

Computers don't story a base-10 numerical digit in one byte. Each byte actually can hold 256 different possible values.